# How to fix Visual Studio 2017 Community install error - Couldn't download 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi.msi'?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When trying to install Visual Studio 2017 Community I got the error:
Couldn't download 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi.msi'
Error 0x80096004 there is a problem verifying the signature of a certificate.

Windows 10 Pro Version: 20h2
OS build: 19042.804

Visual Studio 2017 Community version: 15.9.33

[[image: VS 2017 Community return error]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spng7.png)

Checking the logs I found it seems that the problem is the hash of the file.

> Error: Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi, version
> = 15.0.27005.2' failed to download from 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/7b52e873-c823-471c-b1e9-ca1224f499fa
> /74a24f8c005b1d09066b357104945dc94d3a18156c0433352a718aefd1a616d7/Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi.msi
> '. WebClient download failed: SHA256 check for
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi.msi' failed. Expected
> hash:
> 74A24F8C005B1D09066B357104945DC94D3A18156C0433352A718AEFD1A616D7,
> Actual hash: FEB8356FD3CF6E8520F3675E426C02C11399F94B4A3B0B4E21A1D5B9.
> Bits download failed: SHA256 check for
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi.msi' failed. Expected
> hash:
> 74A24F8C005B1D09066B357104945DC94D3A18156C0433352A718AEFD1A616D7,
> Actual hash: FEB8356FD3CF6E8520F3675E426C02C11399F94B4A3B0B4E21A1D5B9.
> WinInet download failed: SHA256 check for
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi.msi' failed. Hash
> expected:
> 74A24F8C005B1D09066B357104945DC94D3A18156C0433352A718AEFD1A616D7, real
> hash:
> FEB8356FD3CF6E8520F3675E426C02C11399F94B4A3B0B4E21A1D5AF186192B9,
> Signature: PackageId = Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi;
> PackageAction = DownloadPackage; ReturnCode = 0x80131500

Please, does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Someone from Microsoft support gave me a few steps to do and the problem was fixed.

I did the following:

- I delete all content from the %temp% folder
- I deleted the folder "%programdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2"
- I disabled my antivirus program (Microsoft Defender Antivirus)
- I confirmed that all Windows updates were installed
- I opened the Visual Studio Installer and repaired the VS 2017 Community

Fortunately the error message did not appear anymore, that is, it seems that the installation was successful for the package "Microsoft.VisualStudio.WCF.DiagnosticPack.Msi".

Note: on the day of the problem I even deleted all the contents of the %temp% folder, the Windows updates were the most current (I had just formatted my PC and installed Windows 10), and even then the problem continued however today the repair worked.

Thanks.